# Casting a COMObject of TextBox type to a C# Object

Tags: c#, casting, comobject

I am currently working on a application that communicates with a client.
As  shown below, I have a delegated method that returns the received message as  a ComObject of type TextBox.

```
void mailbox_MessageReceived(ref object ComObj1) {
    string typeName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(ComObj1);
    Console.WriteLine(typeName); //Prints "TextBox"        

    //insert rest of code here
}
```

So far, I have unsuccessfully tried to cast (`ComObj1` as TextBox), and tried to get the `IntPtr` for `ComObj1` to pass as an argument in  `Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant()`, both to no avail.

My question is how should I cast `ComObj1` to a C# Object?

Comment: Did you [see this post, which looks like what you are afer?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12234097/2061309)