# Cast object according to string's value in C#

Tags: c#, string, object, casting

Let's say I have:

```
string ValueToCastTo;
object TheThing;
```

If `ValueToCastTo` is set to `"int"`, I want `TheThing` to be casted to an `int`.
If `ValueToCastTo` is set to `"DateTime"`, I want `TheThing` to be casted to a `DateTime`.

I can't use `if` statements because the string could be set to anything.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Keep in mind here that you can't actually cast an object to anything you want. "Object" is a base level abstraction.  You can only cast TheThing to whatever that object actually is, one of the parents of what that object actually is (which would include "object"), or an interface it implements.

Comment: I need to convert the value of the `ValueToCastTo` into a type so that I can use that to cast the `Object`

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey I can't cast an empty object to something else, then set the properties using reflection?

Comment: If you're going to be using reflection, why don't you just create the specific kind of object you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need:

- [`Type.GetType(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)
- plus a built-in list corresponding to C# keywords, since `GetType` expects `System.Int32` not `int`.
- [`Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx)

Maybe the runtime will figure out the right conversion, but normally it won't.  So also write a whole lot of `TypeConverter` implementations and then use

- [`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewtxwhzx(v=vs.110).aspx) followed by either [`TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef83h055(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`TypeConverter.ConvertTo(object, Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13battt(v=vs.110).aspx) depending on which type knows about the other one

and when you're done, the static type will still be `object`.  But it'll be a handle to an instance of your new type.  Whether that helps you depends on exactly what you want to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

TypeOf() you can use to get the type and then do reflection.

"C# - Reflection objects are used for obtaining type information at runtime. The classes that give access to the metadata of a running program are in the System.Reflection namespace."

You can follow that path to get what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Something similar as it explains in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234097/how-to-cast-object-to-its-actual-type

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

A cast is something you have to write at compile time, to assign a variable of type X an object of type Y. 
A cast imply that you know at compile time the type you want to assign to, so you can write something such

```
int x = (int) y;
string x = (string) y;
```

There are workarounds to this: use `TypeOf()` on your object, use reflection to detect at runtime type, properties and methods of the object, or use `dynamic` to avoid compile time checks.

But it actually depends on what you are trying to get from your code.