# How to get Values from variable of type Object in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have a variable of type Object which is typeof InquireSubscription

```
public class InquireSubscription: object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public string planId {get; set}
}
```

I want to retrieve the planId value but i am totally stuck in finding out how to access the properties out of the Object item

Please have a look at the Screenshot:

[image]

**EDITED** `eligibilityResult` is of type SubscriptionEligibility

```
    public partial class SubscriptionEligibility: object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
         private object[] itemsField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("InquireSubscription", typeof(SubscriptionEligibility), Order=0)]

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DeviceEligibilityResult", typeof(SubscriptionEligibility), Order=0)]

       public object[] Items {
           get {
             return this.itemsField;
           } 
           set {
              this.itemsField = value;
              this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
           }
        }
```

Comment: You can use `dynamic` or reflection, but you *really* shouldn't if you can avoid it. What is the type of `eligibilityResult.Items`? If it's a strongly typed collection, replace `object item` with `var item`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast Object to its actual type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234097/how-to-cast-object-to-its-actual-type)

Comment: What is the type of eligibilityResult.Items? Can you post your code? You should be able to write `foreach(InquireSubscribtion item in eligibilityResult)` in your code.

Comment: A side note, all classes inherit from `object` by default so you don't need to specify that.

Comment: The tooltip will tell you what type to use for `item`, or you could just write `foreach (var item in...` and then referencing `item.planId` will just work.

Comment: Edited my post for further clarity

Comment: @iakobski I get error `object' does not contain a definition for 'planId' and no extension method 'planId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found` when I reference like `item.planId`

Comment: `SubscriptionEligibility.Items` should be `InquireSubscription[]`, not `object[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
foreach (var item in eligibilityResult.Items.OfType<InquireSubscription>())
{
    item.planId = ...;
}
```

This will ignore any Items that are not `InquireSubscription` or a subclass. Use Cast() if you want to be sure that it isn't the case:

```
foreach (var item in eligibilityResult.Items.Cast<InquireSubscription>())
{
    item.planId = ...;
}
```

If you own the code of `SubscriptionEligibility` you should instead try to refactor it to not use `object` if possible

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't refactor SubscriptionEligibility. But, your `OfType` solution will work