# how can I parse object into a class like json deserialize?

Tags: c#

I want to make a own parser that can parse object values into the `<T>` Type that contains class with propertys.

the class `ASObject` is just a `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
  public class Example {

    public string User { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

  }

  public static class ServiceResultParser<T>
  {
      public static T Parse(ASObject AS)
      {
          foreach(var l in AS.Values)
          {

          }
      }
  }

Usage:

var Result = ServiceResultParser.Parse<Example>(theobject);
string User = Result.User;
```

that is only a test class that I called `Example` 
in json we can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value)`
  **and no I dont want parse json.**
how can I now parse the value into the `Example` class?

regarding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234097/how-to-cast-object-to-its-actual-type

Comment: @ZakkDiaz this is not what I m looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check wheter T has a property with a name that matches the Dictionary's key:

```
  public static class ServiceResultParser<T> where T : new()
  {
      public static T Parse(ASObject AS)
      {
          var temp = GetObject();
          foreach(var l in AS)
          {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if(property.Name == l.Key) property.SetValue(temp, l.Value);
                }
          }
          return temp;
      }
        protected T GetObject()
        {
            return new T();
        }
  }
```

You should also check if the properties type match, etc...

Comment: hey thanxs for answer. 
how can I now return the Typeargument?

Comment: Are you talking about setting the value of that property to the one on the dictionaty?

Comment: i updated my answer, i haven't tested it sicne i'm on phone but you should get the point

Comment: that works perfect ! :D but you cant do protected in a static class so I made the protected as private ! thanxs !

Comment: hey @Alex Coronas how can I set the property value if there is a List?

Comment: Create a empty list and add every member, maybe