# How to retrieve a list stored in an Object class

Tags: c#, list, object, console

```cs
public class A
{
    public long TestCaseId { get; set; }
    public byte TestCaseNumber { get; set; }

    public object FetchList { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> a = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        List<A> Objectlst = new List<A>();
        Objectlst .Add(new A { TestCaseId = 1, TestCaseNumber = 1, FetchList = a });
        foreach (var item in Objectlst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.FetchList);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a list of class `A`. If I am assigning a generic list to Object datatype `FetchList`, 
Can someone tell me how to retrieve all the values stored in list through this property `FetchList`?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(item.FetchList as List<int>);`

Comment: I think you can find something here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234097/how-to-cast-object-to-its-actual-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast Object to its actual type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234097/how-to-cast-object-to-its-actual-type)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in Objectlst)
{
    var list = item.FetchList as List<int>;
    if (list != null)
        foreach (int num in list)
            Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but what if I don't know the type of list example, in here you used as List<int> but what if you don't know the type of list i.e it is not generic some random class type.

Comment: @SiddharthDwivedi Then you shouldn't be using `object`.  Sure, you can discover type information at runtime with reflection, but C# is a strongly-typed language.  So use compile time type safety is my advice.