# How do you access the properties of an object when that object is the value of a key/value pair in a dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, hashtable

C#:
I have this dictionary:
Dictionary<string, Object> ourAnimals = new ();

Each key is a string, such as "d1".

Each value is an object. Here is the class definition for those objects:
class Pet {

```
    public string species;
    public string age;
    public string physicalDescription;
    public string personalityDescription;
    public string nickname;
    public string suggestedDonation;

    public Pet(string Species, string Age, string PhysicalDescription, string PersonalityDescription, string Nickname, string SuggestedDonation) {

            species = Species;
            age = Age;
            physicalDescription = PhysicalDescription;
            personalityDescription = PersonalityDescription;
            nickname = Nickname;
            suggestedDonation = SuggestedDonation;

    }

    void printPet() {

         Console.WriteLine(nickname);   
         Console.WriteLine(species);   
         Console.WriteLine(age);   
         Console.WriteLine(physicalDescription);   
         Console.WriteLine(personalityDescription);   
         Console.WriteLine(suggestedDonation);   
    }
```

}

What I'd like to do is print the key/value pairs (formatted, of course) of each item in the dictionary.

I even included a method to print the values of the object, should I not find a way to do the above. I can't even figure out how to call that for each dictionary entry.

How do I access the values and/or method of those objects in the dictionary?
I had the same problem in PowerShell.

Incidentally, trying to do a web search on this question only results in about a million pages on how to create objects or dictionaries, but not how to handle dictionaries of objects, or dictionaries of dictionaries for that matter.

BTW, you may recognize this example as part of the c# tutorials on learn.microsoft.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How to iterate over a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/how-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary) and [How to cast Object to its actual type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234097/how-to-cast-object-to-its-actual-type)

Comment: You should avoid using the `System.Object` type - do you have a good reason for using `Object` instead of `Pet`?

Comment: I do know how to iterate over a dictionary if the value of the kvp is a simple data type, but if the value is an object, I don't know how to access that object's properties. (to shingo's reply). (To Dai's reply) Why would I avoid using an Class?

Comment: An object is an object. If I told you there was a cake in a spaceship, would you say that you didn't know how to eat a cake that was in a spaceship? Of course not, because that would be ridiculous. A cake is a cake, whether it's in a spaceship or a cardboard box on your kitchen table. If you know how to access the properties of an object, why would where you get that object from make any difference? You access the properties the same way regardless.

Comment: OT, don't have public fields in a class. Use properties to expose data publicly. In this case, use auto-properties. If you need more advanced functionality, use a fully-implemented property with a private backing field and add the functionality to the getter and/or setter.

Comment: @LanceM, the second question explains, you need convert the object to Pet.

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates almost everything for you to start:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace NsPetDictionary {
    class Pet {
        public Pet(string species, int age, string nickname) {
            Species = species; Age = age; Nickname = nickname;
            PhysicalDescription = PersonalityDescription = ""; SuggestedDonation = 100;
        }
        public string Species { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string PhysicalDescription { get; set; }
        public string PersonalityDescription { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public int SuggestedDonation { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() {
            return String.Format("A pretty {0} {1}, {2} requires some donation, maybe {3}\r\n", Species, Nickname, Age, SuggestedDonation)
                + String.Format("    About {0}: {1}, {2}.", Nickname, PhysicalDescription, PersonalityDescription);
        }
    }
    class PetDictionary {
        static void Main() {
            var ourAnimals = new Dictionary<string, Pet> {
                { "animal1", new Pet("cat", 2, "Tom") }
                , { "animal2", new Pet("mouse", 1, "Jerry") }
            };
            ourAnimals["animal1"].PhysicalDescription = "cheeky red beast";
            ourAnimals["animal1"].PersonalityDescription = "kind at heart";
            ourAnimals["animal2"].PhysicalDescription = "small nimble gray";
            ourAnimals["animal2"].PersonalityDescription = "provocative";
            ourAnimals.Add("animal3", new Pet("dog", 5, "Zeus") {
                    PhysicalDescription = "big black with short hair"
                    , PersonalityDescription = "wise calm friend"
                    , SuggestedDonation = 300 } );
            Console.WriteLine("Recently suggested donation is {0}", ourAnimals["animal3"].SuggestedDonation);
            Console.WriteLine("Our pets are:");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Pet> kvp in ourAnimals) Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Class Pet is the set of data about a pet with a single method to display pet's info.

Method Main demonstrates how to create the Dictionary with some initial elements, then how to access dictionary's element and its properties.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: @Dai This is an unsubstantiated argument. I certify that the answer is entirely my own.

Comment: I'm suspicious because the code looks very similar to what ChatGPT gave me right now when I asked it to give me an example program based on the same question as the OP _and_ you sure seem to have put in _a lot_  of effort into an example program with lots of extraneous detail for a trivial question that's going to end-up closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Dai it means I have a bit of free time to provide the extended answer. May be ChartGPT is not so busy too... :-)